# Composite foreign key or one foreign key for each column

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

I'm designing a SQL Server 2012 database with these three tables `ProductionOrder`, `VariableData` and `AggregationLevelConfiguration` (there are more):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductionOrder]
(
    [ProductionOrderId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1), 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 

    [...], 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ProductionOrderId] ASC
    )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AggregationLevelConfiguration]
(
    [AggregationLevelConfigurationId] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [ProductionOrderId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 

    [...], 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AggregationLevelConfiguration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [AggregationLevelConfigurationId] ASC,
        [ProductionOrderId] ASC
    ), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationLevelConfiguration_ProductionOrder] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductionOrderId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductionOrder] ([ProductionOrderId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VariableData]
(
    [VariableDataId] VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    [ProductionOrderId] INT NOT NULL,
    [AggregationLevelConfigurationId] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [Value] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 

    [...], 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_VariableData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ProductionOrderId] ASC,
        [AggregationLevelConfigurationId] ASC
    ), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableData_ProductionOrder] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductionOrderId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductionOrder] ([ProductionOrderId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

My problem is in the last table, `VariableData`. I don't know how to put the foreign key relationship between it and `AggregationLevelConfiguration`. I think there are two options:

Put two foreign keys, one to `ProductionOrder` table, and other one to `AggregationLevelConfiguration` table.

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableData_ProductionOrder] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductionOrderId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductionOrder] ([ProductionOrderId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableData_AggregationLevel] FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationLevelConfigurationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AggregationLevelConfiguration] ([AggregationLevelConfigurationId])
```

Put one foreign key to `AggregationLevelConfiguration` table for `ProductionOrderId` and `AggregationLevelConfigurationId` columns.

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_VariableData_ProductionOrder] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductionOrderId], [AggregationLevelConfigurationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AggregationLevelConfiguration] ([ProductionOrderId], [AggregationLevelConfigurationId])
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to tie `VariableData` to `AggregationLevelConfiguration` via `AggregationLevelConfigurationId`, and rely on the `ProductionOrderId` in `AggregationLevelConfiguration` when I need to go back to the `ProductionOrder` table.

Generally, it's best to denormalize data only when absolutely necessary for some reason (usually performance; in rare cases, possibly security concerns).

Also - I don't see any particular benefit to including `ProductionOrderId` as a part of the primary key for `AggregationLevelConfiguration`. You're not grouping data by it, to try to make sure all configurations for the same `ProductionOrderId` are contiguous; since the key is clustered, it's already going to be available as a part of the index (clustered indexes define the order in which the data is stored, and all fields are "included"); and (I assume) `AggregationLevelConfigurationId` is a unique value, so your selectivity doesn't improve. Also, remember that a primary key is stored as the pointer to records in other indexes, and used as the key value that must be provided for all foreign keys to the table. "Wide" keys are generally not a good idea.

Similarly, using `ProductionOrderId` and `AggregationLevelConfigurationId` as the primary key for the `VariableData` isn't necessarily a great idea. They won't form a unique value, and all the best primary keys do (those that don't have a value added to them by SQL Server to force uniqueness). And, of course, I recommended that you drop one of those columns.

It looks like `VariableDataId` might not be unique (it might, but I could see someone wanting the same variable name tied to different configuration levels). If it is unique, but user-facing, I'd be inclined to create a non-user-facing surrogate key (probably an IDENTITY column). Users will eventually want to change user-facing values, and it's nice to minimize the need to change the value of a primary key. Note that different people feel differently about this. Again, I'd be disinclined to include `AggregationLevelConfigurationId` as a column in the primary key for `VariableData`.

Note: There could, in theory, be some benefit to having `ProductionOrderId` as the *first* column in the primary key for `AggregationLevelConfiguration`, or `AggregationLevelConfigurationId` as the *first* column in the `VariableData` primary key, with the actual unique key value as the second column. All the `AggregationLevelConfiguration` rows for a given `ProductionOrder`, or `VariableData` rows for a given `AggregationLevelConfiguration`, would be stored together. If you normally need to access all records for a parent together, this could provide a slight performance boost. However, adding new `AggregationLevelConfiguration` rows is more likely to cause a page split, as the rows won't always be added to the end of the table (as happens normally with an IDENTITY column). If new levels or variable data are frequently added over the course of time, that can be a concern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I have to explain my model: there will be a lot of Production orders, each of them with Aggregation levels (all of them identified by the same `AggregationLevelConfigurationId`, so to identify uniquely I need to use `ProductionOrderId` and `AggregationLevelConfigurationId ` as primary key). If I'm using Production Order to get all the data, I think I need a foreign key to it from `VariableData` table, but I can't do that because an error in SQL.

Comment: If there will be multiple (abbreviating) ALC records with the same ALC Id but different PO Ids, logically there would be some common connection between these ALC records. That might imply that there would be another table, perhaps `[AggregationLevelConfigurationType]`, that would define these common aspects. Now, maybe there's nothing that would go in that table; however, I would think you might at least want to establish human-meaningful names for these types. If that's the case, I would be inclined to create a surrogate key for `AggregationLevelConfiguration`.